upgrading sbt in spark project from 0.13.15 to 1.7.3
I upgraded java version used by jenkins from java 8 to java 17, so the assembly for spark projects is not working showing that
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
[error]     at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Md5Utils.java:104)
[error]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1644)
[error]     at fm.sbt.S3URLHandler.putImpl$1(S3URLHandler.scala:344)
[error]     at fm.sbt.S3URLHandler.upload(S3URLHandler.scala:356)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerDispatcher.upload(URLHandlerDispatcher.java:82)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository.java:84)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$LocalIfFileRepo.put(ConvertResolver.scala:368)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put(ConvertResolver.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver.put$(ConvertResolver.scala:105)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.ConvertResolver$$anonfun$defaultConvert$lzycompute$1$PluginCapableResolver$1.put(ConvertResolver.scala:165)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)

and when i added this :  "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.1" , i got :
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/jars/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:javax/xml/bind/util/Messages.class
[error] /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2/cache/net.snowflake/snowflake-ingest-sdk/jars/snowflake-ingest-sdk-0.10.8.jar:javax/xml/bind/util/Messages.class

